# How do you get the marker squares to be exact squares with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

To begin with, it is important that I do this with plt.scatter and not by iterating over the points (patches), because with my real data I have huge amounts of data points.  The question is about how to solve this with plt.scatter and finding the right marker size.

With this small example, I would like to achieve the following:

1. For each of my 16 data points, one square on the picture should be plotted in a color specific to this point.
2. Depending on the figsize, I need to work out the exact number of data points the marker needs to be.

My strategy:
 a) Use ax.transData.transform to get the pixel values for 0,0, 0,1, 0,2
   and 1,0, 2,0, 3,0 to verify that the distances are equal. 
 b) Multiply the width with the height to get the size of the marker I need. 
 c) Convert from pixels to points.
 d) Feed this marker to plt.scatter.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xdim = 4
figs = 5
dpi = 100

fig = plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(figs, figs), dpi=dpi, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
plt.xlim((-1,5))
plt.ylim((-1,5))

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x = np.arange(0+.5, xdim+.5, 1)
y = np.arange(0+.5, xdim+.5, 1)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

Z= np.random.rand(xdim*xdim,3)

x_diff = np.diff(ax.transData.transform([(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,4)]),axis=0)
y_diff = np.diff(ax.transData.transform([(0,0),(1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(4,0)]),axis=0)

print(x_diff,y_diff)

x_avg = np.average(x_diff[0,1])
y_avg = np.average(y_diff[1,0])

print(x_avg,y_avg)

marker_pixels = x_avg*y_avg
marker_points = (marker_pixels*72)/dpi

print marker_points

plt.scatter(X,Y,c=Z, s=marker_points, marker='s', edgecolors=None)

plt.savefig('foo.png', dpi=dpi)
```

However, the results I get are 66.666 (fact!) and 64.58 in this example, i.e, not a square. When I multiply the two, convert and feed to plt.scatter I get this image out:
[image]

As you can see the squares are not squares, and don't exactly fill out the square from 0,0 to 1,1, etc.  If you use fig.show() this will be more clear to see.

This approximate solution is ok, as the grid is very large it looks fine, but I wonder how I can solve this exactly.  How can I make sure that the markers are placed exactly within the square it is supposed to fit, filling from 0,1 on both axes for the bottom left square?

Comment: It looks to me like these are just a little too big and overlapping with (4,4) on top, giving the irregular visible patches. What does it look like if you make them translucent?

Comment: They will overlap each other slightly.  The big question here is really the report from ax.transData.transform().  Why are there different distances on the x- and y axes?

Comment: have you set `aspect=square` anywhere? Sometimes it's `equal`.

Comment: I have just the MWE I presented, where would I put `aspect=equal`in there?  In the call to plt.figure?

Comment: aspect belongs to axes, not figures; check out `help(plt.axis)`

Comment: Thanks.  But I think I'll stop digging in this now although it made me curious, since your solution below worked nicely.  Quick and lean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general answer is probably Patches, not marker squares, however slow it is. However, using the grid nature of the sample you show, there's a much easier way, and you can still do other plotting over it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy.random as nr
quilt = nr.random((4,4))


plt.imshow(quilt, interpolation='none', aspect='equal', cmap=cm.jet)
plt.scatter([1,2,3],[3,0,1])
plt.plot([0,1,1.4, 2.3, 3.5],[0,1,2,3,2])
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can change the axis ticks to represent your data units, customize the colormap to have transparent squares for missing data, embed the imshow as a subplot in another figure, etc. etc.

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted.  In my real data, I have the color codes coded as 4-dimensional vectors, and then I need to make annotations inside each square. Reshaping my (xdim*xdim,4) matrix into (xdim,xdim,4) worked perfectly as input to imshow(). (Now I had to do some pixel arithmetic to find out how much to offset the text).