# Python Matplotlib Plot Scatter plot over contourf or imshow

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

following problem:
I have surface data which I can plot as imshow or contourf, my next step is to plot certain points given in a np.mesgrid array as scatter plot over the contourf. My code gives no failure, but does not show the scatter plot over the contour

```
fig1=plt.figure()
#plate=plt.imshow(twi, vmin=-1, vmax=2, origin='lower',extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()], interpolation='bilinear')
plate=plt.contourf(xi,yi,twi,21,vmin=-1, vmax=2)
plt.colorbar()
plt.scatter(xx_sensor,yy_sensor,marker='o', c='b', s=5, zorder=10,lw=100)
plt.xlim(x.min(), x.max())
plt.ylim(y.min(), y.max())
plt.show()
```

Comment: have you checked, that the scatter points are somewhere within the viewpoint specified by your `xlim` and `ylim` bounds?

Comment: It should be easy over imshow (works here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28905195/how-do-you-get-the-marker-squares-to-be-exact-squares-with-matplotlib/28908824#28908824).

Comment: oh so stupid, you were right, the limits of x- and y-range were set in a wrong way...thanks a lot!